# java: cannot access org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: class not found

Tags: java, maven, cassandra

Trying to use `EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();` method but keep getting this error. I can go to each class for the exceptions thrown in that method, besides the configurationException class. Not sure why it's not picking it up. I posted all the dependencies I have below, hoping someone here can maybe see something I missed. Thank you

Exact error is `java: cannot access org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException class file for org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException not found`

pom file is

````
<dependencies>
        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.web.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- apache commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- apache client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.httpcomponents.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cassandra -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- voltage -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanio</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanio</artifactId>
            <version>${beanio.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.handler.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a symptom of another problem. In my experience, "class not found" exceptions are common with using newer versions of Java when running Cassandra.

Cassandra 3.11 and earlier versions only work with Java 8. [Java 11 support](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.2/CHANGES.txt#L2) was not added until Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16894)).

It is possible to build your app with newer versions of Java but you won't be able to run Cassandra unless you use a supported JVM. Cheers!